# Check that object is one of many types in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following classes:

```
sealed class A : BaseType
sealed class B : BaseType
sealed class C : BaseType

...
```

If I then have a `processObject` method that looks like this:

```
fun processObject(obj: BaseType): Int {
  return when(obj) {
    is A -> 1
    is B -> 1
    else -> 0
  }
}
```

I notice that I am now repeating myself, so I might change that method to something like this:

```
fun processObject(obj: BaseType): Int {
  return when(obj) {
    is A, is B -> 1
    else -> 0
  }
}
```

However, this (in my opinion) looks super ugly when the number of classes goes from say 3-4 to 40+. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of the pseudocode below:

```
// store all the possible types in a list
val typesThatShouldReturn1 = listOf<BaseType>(
  // TODO: figure out how to store types in a list without instantiating
)

fun processObject(obj: BaseType): Int {
  if (typesThatShouldReturn1.any { obj is it }) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}
```

Is this even possible in kotlin?

---

**Re: some comments.**

Why am I not using a marker interface? Because this `processEvent` function will be implemented in a lot of different contexts and introducing a marker interface for each and every one of them isn't a good solution. Additionally, the `baseType` classes are part of a CQRS system where ideally our write logic should not be concerned with our read logic. This is the biggest reason why a marker interface isn't viable for me here.

Why doesn't `BaseType` implement this logic? See comment above about `processEvents` being implemented in different ways in different contexts. In addition, the base type doesn't have the read logic as a concern so that is why it should never implement this.

Does `listOf(A::class, B::class, C::class, ...)` look any better than `is A, is B, is C, ...`? It looks more or less the same. 
Valid point. This one is more personal preference as I don't mind a `private val typesThatShouldReturn1` nearly as much.

Comment: Is there a reason why You can't implement `processObj` as a method of `BaseType` itself? Then subtypes could override the return value, and You wouldn't need any switch or a list.

Comment: introduce a marker `interface` and if a class implements said interface, return `1`

Comment: Note that it should be `listOf<KClass>` or `listOf<Class>`, not `BaseType`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov or even better: `listOf<KClass<out BaseType>>`

Comment: You may add a method to your `BaseType` (and probably to inheritors) to replace the `when` with the method call. Sometimes it makes sense and simplifies code

Comment: @Lino Oops, yes, of course. Really just `listOf` and let Kotlin infer it :)

Comment: Does `listOf(A::class, B::class, C::class, ...)` look any better than `is A, is B, is C, ...`? It looks more or less the same.

Comment: @SOFe It might be useful if you use the same list (or derived from it) more than once.

Comment: Then you can define it as a function. Look at https://gist.github.com/SOF3/164908f8339508cc07d7e8538116c868

Comment: `when.kt` doesn't really look more verbose than `listOf.kt`. While you can pass a list variable around, you can pass a function around too.

Comment: As long as you don't need to iterate from the list of types, you don't need to store it as an actual list in the heap memory. It could be just hardcoded into the program.

Comment: are all classes part of same package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can write something like this

```
val typesThatShouldReturn1 = listOf(
  A::class
)

fun processObject(obj: BaseType): Int {
  if (typesThatShouldReturn1.any { it.isInstance(obj) }) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}
```

Comment: You can use `in` keyword to test if the list contains `obj::class`

Answer (score 0):

Your example is unclear, but it seems like you were trying to instead do this:

```
sealed class BaseType
class A : BaseType
class B : BaseType
class C : BaseType
```

(which means `BaseType` can only ever be one of `A`, `B`, or `C` — this is consistent with your desired use of `when`)

What you're effectively saying is that `A` and `B` are fundamentally similar and should be handled the same. Assuming `A` and `B` actually need to be separate classes, a solution is that they share a common superclass that is not actually `BaseType`:

```
sealed class BaseType
open class ABCommon : BaseType
class C : BaseType

class A : ABCommon
class B : ABCommon

fun processObject(obj: BaseType): Int {
  return when(obj) {
    is ABCommon -> 1
    else -> 0
  }
}
```

Comment: See my edit in the question. Adding a marker interface (or open class inheritance) is not an option because while `A` and `B` are treated identically in this scenario, they might not be in another similar scenario. If we follow this approach, we are gonna need `ACCommon` next and `BCCommon` after that and that is simply not possible because Kotlin does not allow multiple inheritance and even if it did, this leads to putting parts of the read logic into the write model which is a line we aren't willing to cross.

Comment: @ArnabDatta: Missed that, gotcha. I'll leave the answer as-is because it's probably more useful this way for the general case. As for your particular case, I don't think there's an objectively correct answer for your specific question, though — it's down to a matter of taste. I can easily see the switch statement generating more efficient code than having to iterate through a list of classes, though.